# Unable to get the private bytes memory limit for the W3WP process

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7, iis-6

We run several ASP.NET applications on our webfarm, but we noticed a lot of error entry in the event log:

**Unable to get the private bytes memory limit for the W3WP process. The ASP.NET cache will be unable to limit its memory use, which may lead to a process restart.**

We stores the web site files on a network share and the application pools running under the "Network Service" account. We did every recommended step (but the problem still appears):

- aspnet_regiis –ga “Network Service”
- cscript metaacl.vbs IIS://Localhost/W3SVC/AppPools IIS_WPG RE
- Add “Connect As” account to IIS_WPG group.
- Allow "Connect As" accont to logon as a service.

Answer (score 2):

Did you restart the IIS service after having executed the scripts? [This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/carloc/archive/2006/09/20/unable-to-get-the-private-bytes-memory-limit-for-w3wp-exe-process.aspx) also recommends using this statement for granting permissions to the filters:

```
cscript metaacl.vbs IIS://Localhost/W3SVC/Filters IIS_WPG RE
```

This error is caused by a known issue with insufficient permissions in your IIS metabase.

Comment: Yes, we restarted the IIS service...

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility if you moved this service or deprecated a domain or something along those lines is that the nominal IIS_WPG permissions assigned to your metabase are for an outdated SID.

To find out what permissions are actually assigned:

```
cscript metaacl.vbs IIS://Localhost/W3SVC/AppPools
```

If IIS_WPG is not listed but a SID is, run the following to add IIS_WPG:

```
cscript metaacl.vbs IIS://Localhost/W3SVC/AppPools IIS_WPG U
```

The U (unsecured properties read) should be enough for this purpose.